# Function for creating unique strings for urls

Tags: php, strings, random

I wrote this function in order to create unique url's for my site. Using these urls, visitors could demo site functionality without having to create a login.  The function was intended to return a unique string of characters which could be added to a url like this:

http://www.mysite.com?temp_user=dd5vbrk4ax4v4o09l2bm

My function had the following criteria:

1. Every call must generate a unique string of alpha numeric characters.
2. Most important: Zero chance of string duplication.
3. It should be 20 characters long (secure, but not awkwardly long.)
4. Repeat calls should reflect a high degree of dissimilarity.
5. Character usage should appear as random as possible.

Here is my code

```
function url_code(){

  $letters =  "1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
  $microtime = microtime();
  $time_array = explode(' ', substr($microtime,2));
  $code = '';

  $time_array[0] = substr($time_array[0],0,6); 
  $time_array[0] .= strrev($time_array[0]);
  $time_array[2] = strrev($time_array[1]);

  for($i = 0; $i <10; $i++){

    $num = ((int)$time_array[1][$i]);
    $num += ((int)$time_array[2][$i])*10; 
    $num += ((int)$time_array[0][$i])*100;

    $mult   = (int)($num / 36);
    $mod    = $num - ($mult * 36);

    $code  .= $letters[$mult].$letters[$mod];

  }

  return $code;

}
```

Please let me know if there are any simple improvements I could make or if I missed any serious problems with string repetition.

One interesting note on character randomness: currently, characters generated by the $mult variable (the first, third, fifth, and other odd character in the code string) will never be t,u,v,w,x,y, or z. How can I fix this so that [t-z] are also used?

Possible fix (all characters will be used. However, [8-9a-s] are twice as likely to appear as the other characters, [0-7t-z]):

```
$mult   = (int)($num / 36);
$mod    = $num - ($mult * 36);
if($mult < 9 && mt_rand(0,1)){$mult += 27;}

$code  .= $letters[$mult].$letters[$mod];
```

Note, Scalability issue found:  If this function is run on more than one server, there is a tiny chance that two users could send a request at exactly the same time and get a duplicated code.

Answer (score 6):

#### Algorithm

> 1. Every call must generate a unique string of alpha numeric characters.
> 2. Most important: Zero chance of string duplication.

"zero chance" is really hard to achieve, if it's even possible.
Your algorithm is essentially based on the current time in microseconds.
Since systems may adjust their clock, for example with NTP,
the same microsecond may happen again,
resulting in a non-unique string.

Striving for a unique random string is known challenge,
see for example the [`uniqid`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) function.
The documentation offers some recommendations for cryptographic security,
and I think it might be a good idea to incorporate `uniqid` into your algorithm.

> 4. Repeat calls should reflect a high degree of dissimilarity.

If I call the function twice in a row I get values with a similar prefix, for example:

> ```
> qf1p1dojax7n7m08no1f
> qf1p1drbj0nbnahjqg1f
>
> gp70pxdfghnbnaetckpa
> gp70pxg8j0q4q3hlfcpa
> ```

This is because in the microseconds parts are too similar in consecutive calls.
You seem to be using the microseconds part as a 6-digit random number.
You would get better results with a proper pseudo random generator,
for example one of the recommendations from [`uniqid`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php).

#### Readability

The implemented algorithm is quite straightforward:

- Prepare 3 strings of at least 10-digits:

  - a 12-digit string from the first 6 decimal digits of the microseconds elapsed since the current timestamp seconds, concatenated with its reverse
  - a 10-digit string from the current timestamp
  - a 10-digit string from the reverse of the current timestamp
- Count from 0 until 9 to generate a 20-letter string:

  - Create a 3-digit number using i-th positions from the prepared strings
  - Encode the 3-digit number as a base-36 number, so that it becomes a 2-letter string
  - Concatenate the 2-letter encoded strings to get a 20-letter string

Unfortunately this flow of logic is not easy to see in the implementation,
because the variable names are not helping.

- Instead of the array `$time_array`,
  it would be better to use 3 variables with descriptive names.
- If you extract the big logical steps to functions, for example one to generate a 3-digit number, and another to encode a 3-digit number in base-36, the code could read almost like a story.

#### Technique

Instead of `$mod = $num - ($mult * 36)` you could simply use the modulo operator: `$mod = $num % 36`.

Instead of hard-coding 36, which has to be the length of `$letters`,
it would be better to store it in a variable, and derive its value from the length of `$letters`.
So that if one day you change the alphabet (for example add capital letters too),
then you won't have to remember to replace all the 36 with the new value,
the program will "just work".

Instead of implementing base-36 encoding yourself,
you could use the existing [`base_convert`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base-convert.php#52450) function.
It's not 100% the same, because it uses slightly different alphabet,
and you would need to convert the number parameter to string.

Comment: This is a nitpicky comment but I'm making it to clear up my (mis)understanding... I believe NTP won't repeat a millisecond time.  Instead, I think it slowly adjusts to computer clock to the "correct" time such that the values are always monotonic.  There's also monatomic clock to avoid time zone changes.  As a side note, you would have to ensure that your generator function takes longer than the granularity of clock.  Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: @sudorm-rfslash I think that's a very valuable comment, thank you!

Comment: Zero chance of duplication is achievable if you use an encryption and encrypt unique inputs: 0, 1, 2, 3, ...  You will need to play with block sizes and convert the output to number base 36 (or possibly Base32) but the uniqueness requirement is achievable, albeit with a major rewrite of the code.

Answer (score 2):

Don't go about [reinventing-the-wheel](/questions/tagged/reinventing-the-wheel).  **PHP already has a [`uniqid()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) function** that does that.  Like your function, `uniqid()` is just a way of encoding the time, with **no randomness involved**: the results will look dissimilar, but they are not cryptographically unguessable.  It would probably be a good idea to call it with a server-specific prefix, if you are running the application across multiple servers, otherwise collisions would be possible.  You might also want to incorporate the process ID somewhere, if you have multiple instances of the application that can run simultaneously on one server.

If you *truly* want the string to be unique, then follow the wisdom of the standards-makers, and use a [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier).  PHP does not have a UUID function, but Andrew Moore has written a [recipe for generating standard UUIDs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php#94959) in the comments.  (Unfortunately, standard UUIDs would be 36 characters long.)

Comment: I like the idea of including getmypid()

Comment: problem with that function is the warning "This function does not guarantee uniqueness of return value." - in theory you could loop it... other problem it you can only choose 13 or 23 as the length, not 20... also easily solved I guess by trimming the last 3 off. If you review the comment from "hackan at gmail dot com" on the official PHP docs you see will also see some other problems

Answer (score 1):

I would rather use the integrated md5 funcion that should be faster. 
In case it s too long. The string could be shorten.
By the end. There s a probability that the same string is to be generated twice... so bigger is the string and lower is that probability.

Comment: I considered md5, but I wanted zero chance that there could be duplicate strings.

Comment: I just updated the question to contain this criteria.

Comment: Could you not generate the md5, then check the site if the string was allocated before? You must store this somewhere...

Answer (score 0):

Other than what folks have posted here I see little room for improvement, however in my search for a similar process (ensuring unique URLs) I went with these 2 WP functions, just grabbed them and used them to make unique URLs with 20 characters, which I think the likelihood of "repeating" is less 1 than 100 billion

I just grabbed these:

- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_generate_password/
- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_rand/

Here is my final, note the function added to "ensure" the ZERO chance of repeating where you would need to mod stuff

```
function secure_unique_url( $length = 20) {
    $chars = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
    $url= '';
    for ( $i = 0; $i < $length; $i++ ) {
        $url.= substr( $chars, wp_rand( 0, strlen( $chars ) - 1 ), 1 );
    }
    if(url_is_unique()) { 
        return $url;
    } else { 
       // keep doing it till its unique
       return secure_unique_url($length);
    }
    
}

function url_is_unique($url) {
   // query your database and ensure URL does not exist
   return true;
   // if it does
   return false;
}

function wp_rand( $min = 0, $max = 0 ) {
   // take this from https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_rand/
   // note that you need to make a "random_seed" 
   // re: get_transient( 'random_seed' )
   // which is easy, just make one from an MD5 hash
}
```

Comment: This do not look like an efficient approach.  I seek looped trips to the database.

Comment: Whats more important then? The 100% top 2 requirements listed here "#1-Every call must generate a unique string of alpha numeric characters." and "#2-Zero chance of string duplication" or maybe 1 in a million chance of querying a DB for less than 1kb of rez? Because... if you want 0. as in absolute 0.000 chance of duplication. this is the way. Also: the chances of you needing to query that DB are like what... 1 in a million? 1 in a billion? Try it. see how often you would actually have to query the DB to "double check" the URL for a 0 chance of dup.